# Need PHP code clarification for c# code

Tags: c#, php, soap

I have tried to change the C# code to PHP , And I unable to check the authentication success or not.

**C# Code :**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string outStr = "";
BASoapClient baucli = new BAServiceSoapClient();
OfflineHeader oheader = baucli.Authenticate("username", "pwd", "2.9.0.0", EA_ID, out outStr);
doc.LoadXml(outStr);
bool m_Authenticated;
if (doc.DocumentElement.Attributes["Value"].Value.Equals("True")) {
    m_Authenticated = true;
} else {
    string errMsg = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Msg"].Value;
    string action = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Action"].Value;
    if (action.Equals("Version")) {
        string URL = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1].Attributes["URL"].Value;
    }
    m_Authenticated = false;
}
```

**PHP code :**

```
$soapURL = "http://localhost/BWebservice/BWebService.asmx?wsdl";
        $soapParameters = array(
            'Username' => 'muruga',
            'Password' => 'muruga1436',
            'ProductVersion' => '2.9.0.0',
            'EACode' => '175'
            );
        $soapClient = new SoapClient($soapURL);
        $headers = new SoapHeader('http://localhost/BWebservice/BAU', 'UserCredentials', $soapParameters); 
        // Prepare Soap Client 
        $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($headers));
```

Thanks in advance